# GIT: Discrepancy when branching from a previous commit

Tags: git

I have a git tree as follows:

```
a -> b -> c-> d (develop)

Files:
b: f1, f2
c: f2, f2, f3
d: f1, f2, f3, f4
```

I made a branch out of previous commit (b).  I did:
git checkout -b test sha_of_b

```
a -> b -> c-> d (develop)
      \-> e (test)
```

When I use `gitg` to view the tree, it properly lists the files in my test branch as `f1`, `f2`.  However, when I do `ls` in a terminal, I see `f1`,`f2`,`f3` and `f4` (I made sure I am checkout on test branch).  Why this discrepancy? I was expecting `ls` to only show `f1`,`f2`.

I repeated this test in another folder (with simple files actually named as `f1` `f2` etc).  But there I see results as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Have you modified the files? If you have local modifications to the files, then Git won't delete them when switching branches.

What does `git status` show you?

Comment: +1, this confused me also, when you switch branches all non-committed files will be left in the folder, if you're not careful you can end up making a mess.

Comment: When you say "Have you modified the files?", then as far as I remember, f3 and f4 were modified in (d) and committed. f3 and f4 did not even exist as of version (b). I also see that f3 and f4 are not the same as in version (d). Its been a few days since version (b).  It could be possible that I went from b->c by having some older version of f3 and f4 and I never "git add ." them.  But I thought that would mean even the older version of f3 and f4 should not show up.  This experience has left me feeling very scared of using git.